# Wikimedia 1.26.2 VisualEditor IIS 7 on 2008 R2 PHP 5.6 doesn't work

Tags: php, iis, mediawiki

I don't get anything in any log that I can find. The extension simply doesn't work on IIS 7. I setup apache2 on windows and the extension works as expected. I did get an error early on but it was related to curl not being loaded.
 I've tried to debug this but I just don't get any errors.
 If anyone can point me in the right direction I will gladly post back anything that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here, I think the main issue is the line-break style of the scripts, which is incompatible with Windows.

Maybe if you find some batch-editing script replacing it, it would be useful.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. Apache worked just fine with the exact same files.I'm using dokuwiki until wikimedia gets this sorted so probably for the rest of my life.

Comment: That's right, I managed to get it to work without touching the files.

I activated the media uploads on Mediawiki (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads)

And it worked

Comment: Interesting, I'll test that out this weekend. I'm using the same PHP 5.6 install files and config for both IIS and Apache with only the tweaks that have to be done for IIS to work.